# ESP8266 Air Quality Sensor CCS811

Tags: arduino, sensors, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am doing a project where I have to connect an ESP8266 NodeMcu v1 board (attached photo) and a CCS811 air quality sensor. Attached photo of the connection.
[Connection Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmkzh.jpg)

In arduino I have version 2.7.4 of esp8266 installed. I have installed the "Adafruit_CCS811.h" library and I am trying to run the example called "CCS811_test":

```
#include "Adafruit_CCS811.h"

Adafruit_CCS811 ccs;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("CCS811 test");

  if(!ccs.begin()){
    Serial.println("Failed to start sensor! Please check your wiring.");
    while(1);
  }

  // Wait for the sensor to be ready
  while(!ccs.available());
}

void loop() {
  if(ccs.available()){
    if(!ccs.readData()){
      Serial.print("CO2: ");
      Serial.print(ccs.geteCO2());
      Serial.print("ppm, TVOC: ");
      Serial.println(ccs.getTVOC());
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("ERROR!");
      while(1);
    }
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

The problem is that when I open the Serial Monitor, I get

> Failed to start sensor! Please check your wiring.

I think the connection is well made, so I don't know what that error might be due to.

Comment: were you going to set D3 into LOW ? I see no such attempt in your code. Connect WAKE to the ground for the test - docs state that: **"Don't forget to tie WAKE to Ground"**

Comment: I have connected pin WAKE to GND but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: When running i2c_scanner I get "No I2C devices found"